# Jmeter returning 400 bad request on a perfectly valid GET request

Tags: http, get, jmeter

I have a valid HTTP GET request which is returning a 200 OK on both curl and postman, however, when run in Jmeter it keeps returning a 400 bad Request with a response body as follows

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "&#91;no&#32;URL&#93;", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;2ea93d42&#46;1511385794&#46;51815e
</BODY></HTML>
```

Not sure what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add a Content-Type to `application/json` in `Http-header-manager`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and i added the baseURL value to the 'Host' parameter in Header section.

eg: if your site's baseURL is "http://test.com".

In Header manager section ->
add Host: test.com

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you add a Header Manager as child of your HTTP Request and add headers:

> Content-Type : application/json

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured it out. For some odd reason when I put the whole url string in the "path" field, the test works as expected i.e. returns a 200. Don't ask me why that is, perhaps something for Apache folks to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just put HTTP Header Manager above your request and add this:

> Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded